# How to add a "add likes" feature on a Flask-SQLAlchemy app?

Tags: python, routes, flask-sqlalchemy

For this twitter-style app, I'm trying to implement a "add likes" feature that will allow a user to like a post without refreshing the page. My app has the following model and relationships:

```
class Follows(db.Model):
"""Connection of a follower <-> followed_user."""

__tablename__ = 'follows'

user_being_followed_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="cascade"),
    primary_key=True,
)

user_following_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="cascade"),
    primary_key=True,
)

class Likes(db.Model):
"""Mapping user likes to warbles."""

__tablename__ = 'likes' 

id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    primary_key=True
)

user_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='cascade')
)

message_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('messages.id', ondelete='cascade'),
    unique=True
)

class User(db.Model):
"""User in the system."""

__tablename__ = 'users'

id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    primary_key=True,
)

email = db.Column(
    db.Text,
    nullable=False,
    unique=True,
)

username = db.Column(
    db.Text,
    nullable=False,
    unique=True,
)

image_url = db.Column(
    db.Text,
    default="/static/images/default-pic.png",
)

header_image_url = db.Column(
    db.Text,
    default="/static/images/warbler-hero.jpg"
)

bio = db.Column(
    db.Text,
)

location = db.Column(
    db.Text,
)

password = db.Column(
    db.Text,
    nullable=False,
)

messages = db.relationship('Message')

followers = db.relationship(
    "User",
    secondary="follows",
    primaryjoin=(Follows.user_being_followed_id == id),
    secondaryjoin=(Follows.user_following_id == id)
)

following = db.relationship(
    "User",
    secondary="follows",
    primaryjoin=(Follows.user_following_id == id),
    secondaryjoin=(Follows.user_being_followed_id == id)
)

likes = db.relationship(
    'Message',
    secondary="likes"
)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"<User #{self.id}: {self.username}, {self.email}>"

def is_followed_by(self, other_user):
    """Is this user followed by `other_user`?"""

    found_user_list = [user for user in self.followers if user == other_user]
    return len(found_user_list) == 1

def is_following(self, other_user):
    """Is this user following `other_use`?"""

    found_user_list = [user for user in self.following if user == other_user]
    return len(found_user_list) == 1

@classmethod
def signup(cls, username, email, password, image_url):
    """Sign up user.

    Hashes password and adds user to system.
    """

    hashed_pwd = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('UTF-8')

    user = User(
        username=username,
        email=email,
        password=hashed_pwd,
        image_url=image_url,
    )

    db.session.add(user)
    return user

@classmethod
def authenticate(cls, username, password):
    """Find user with `username` and `password`.

    This is a class method (call it on the class, not an individual user.)
    It searches for a user whose password hash matches this password
    and, if it finds such a user, returns that user object.

    If can't find matching user (or if password is wrong), returns False.
    """

    user = cls.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

    if user:
        is_auth = bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password)
        if is_auth:
            return user

    return False

class Message(db.Model):
"""An individual message ("warble")."""

__tablename__ = 'messages'

id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    primary_key=True,
)

text = db.Column(
    db.String(140),
    nullable=False,
)

timestamp = db.Column(
    db.DateTime,
    nullable=False,
    default=datetime.utcnow(),
)

user_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer,
    db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
    nullable=False,
)

user = db.relationship('User')
```

I have created a route to handle this feature but I just cannot figure out how to make it work:

```
@app.route('/users/add_like/<int:message_id>', methods=["POST"])
def messages_like(message_id):
"""Like a message."""

msg = Message.query.filter_by(id=message_id)
like = Likes.query.filter_by(
    user_id=user.id, message_id=message_id).first()

if not message:
    flash('Post does not exist', category='error')
elif like:
    db.session.delete(like)
    db.session.commit()
else:
    like = Likes(user_id=user.id, message_id=message_id)
    db.session.add(like)
    db.session.commit()

return render_template('messages/show.html', message=msg)
```

I know that in this route, "user" is not defined but it's just my latest in several attempts of guesses at this point. I imagine that is not the main problem in why this route is not working. I'm also aware that "return render_template" will refresh my page but that is the least of my concerns right now, just a placeholder for now really.

I'm fairly new to Flask-SQLAlchemy and I definitely find the various relationships between tables confusing so I'd appreciate a hand in this and an explanation for how it works and, if possible, how I went wrong.

Comment: To make any changes without refreshing the page, you need to use javascript in your html template.

Comment: Could you explain what problem you are encountering? Have you set up an AJAX request as @AndrewClark has suggested?